# LINQ Left Outer join with group by count through extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables. `Categories` and `Ads`.

Every `Category` can have many ads in `Ads` table.

I want all the categories details including how many ads do they have each.

Following is my Linq expression it fetches only categories that have ads may be bacause `FirstOrDefault()`

I like to know how I can achieve the result given that the condition plus only categories that have location id (let say: lid) of "7".

Following in my expression

```
var x1 = context.Categories
                .GroupJoin(
                    context.ads,
                    cat => cat.id,
                    ad => ad.catid,
                    (cat, ad) => new { cats = cat, ads = ad })
                .SelectMany(
                    a => a.ads.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (a, y) => new { catss = a.cats, adss = y })
                .GroupBy(w => w.adss,ww=>new {  cat=ww.catss,count=ww.catss.ads.Count()})
                .Where(s=>s.FirstOrDefault().cat.lid==7);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
var result = context.Categories
                    .Where(category => category.lid == 7)
                    .GroupJoin(
                        context.ads
                        , category => category.id
                        , ad => ad.catid
                        , (c,a) => new 
                        { 
                            Category = category, 
                            NumberOfAds = a.DefaultIfEmpty().Count(x => x!=null)
                        });
```

Comment: I am looking for extension method solution

Comment: @Alex updated. Please let me know if that is what you need.

Comment: I want all the categories regardless they have ads or not. If there are no ads then count should be 0.

Comment: @Alex From your comment I suppose that the above query doesn't solve your problem. So, let's make clear something that I migh have misunderstood. Don't you want only categories with location id 7? You have stated explicitly this  `given that the condition plus only categories that have location id (let say: lid) of "7".` If you have epxressed correctly what you are looking for, how is that possible to get all the categories?

Comment: @Christos 's answer is well written at all. You can improve it to desired format with little changes on _GroupBy_ and _Select_ clauses.

Comment: @Alex I probably get you argument regarding regardless they have ads or not and I corrected it. However you should make clear that you need only the categories with location id of 7 or all the categories irrespectivelly their location or something else...

Comment: @Christos sorry for confusion. I want categories that are lid 7. there are 31 rows in category table with this but only two have any ads

Comment: @Alex Ok, then the above query should return that you want. Could you please verify this and let me know? Thanks

Comment: @Alex Great ! I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is a one-to-many relation between `Categories` and `Ads`: every `Category` has zero or more `Ads`, and every `Ad` belongs to exactly one `Category`.

In proper Entity Framework this would be modelled as follows:

```
class Category
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every Category has zero or more Adds:
    public virtual ICollection<Ad> Ads {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Ad
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // every Ad belongs to exactly one Category, using foreign key CategoryId:
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public Category Category {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

If your classes are modelled like this, entity framework will assume the proper one-to-many relationship between Category and Add. It might be that you have different names for certain properties, and that you use Attributes and / or fluent API, but the structure of the classes will be similar.

Having done this, your query is easier than you thought:

```
var result = dbContext.Categories.Select(category => new
{
    Category = Category,
    AdCount = Category.Adds.Count(),
};
```

In words: for each Category in the collection of categories, create a new object of anonymous class, with two properties:

- Category contains the considered Category
- AdCount contains the number of Ads that the Category has.

The model of Entity Framework will understand that a join and a count is needed to do this.

Comment: thanks for answer but accepted answer exhibits left outer join which was asked but for good answer deserves +1